# Is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - updated_time same as TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, updated_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I wrote a sql to calculate time diff between now and last updated time. Firstly I just use  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - updated_time` and found the result looks like correct in time unit second. But it wasn't stable, sometimes the result went to much bigger that correct one. And then I changed to  `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, updated_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )` , everything is OK. My question is what's the difference of tow expressions?

Comment: Do you have any more questions or do you want to have something more cleared?

Comment: I want to know more details about how mysql explain "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - updated_time" in it's sql engine.

Comment: I see, now it is clear!  I have revised my answer to be correct, added examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are synonyms for `NOW()` which gives your current time.

**Edit2:**
After your additional comment I understood what you are asking. (I have deleted the first edit) which was incomplete and somewhat incorrect.

The question is: "To explain inner workings of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - updated_time`."

The explanation (I went way deeper):
The `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` can return date and time in  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.
What maybe confused you is that it can return either string or numeric value based on the context.
Here you have a numeric context as you have the - (minus) operator.

```
`String context`
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
        -> '2017-07-04 08:50:26'
OR
`numeric context`
SELECT NOW() + 0;
        -> 20170704085026
```

The - (minus) operator only appears to work:

```
mysql> insert into temp (first, second)
    -> VALUES ('2017-07-01 03:00:00', '2017-07-01 03:01:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select first, second, second - first from temp;
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| first               | second              | first - second |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2017-07-01 03:00:00 | 2017-07-01 03:00:37 | 37.000000      |
| 2017-07-01 03:00:00 | 2017-07-01 03:01:00 | 100.000000     |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Oh nice! 100 seconds in a minute? I don't think so! :).

To correctly subtract your time (if `updated_time` is in seconds):
The `TIME_TO_SEC` is needed: `TIME_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - updated_time`